# Repurpose 2006 Mac Mini for Time Machine with external HDD

Tags: time-machine, mac-mini, external-disk, raid

I have a Apple Mac mini "Core Duo" 1.66 from 2006 sitting around. I also have on order a CiT 3.5 inch USB 2.0 Dual SATA HDD Enclosure and was thinking of getting a WD Green 4TB Desktop Internal SATA Hard Drive to put in it.

Can I set the Mac Mini to mount the USB HDD and use the 4tb as the TimeMachine for my Macbook and iMac?

Do I need to worry about the Mac Mini not being able to run 10.9 OSX or about the type/make of HDD I put in the caddy?

If I add a second HDD can the Mac Mini JBOD or RAID them in the caddy to expand storage size?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: I'm a little confused by your wording. Are you asking if you can hook your Mac Mini up to a MacBook and use the Mac Mini's drive as an external HDD for Time Machine?

Comment: Sorry for poor wording. The Mini would be on my LAN. It has an 80gb SDD in it. I would plug into it a USB HDD caddy that has two SATA 3.5'hdd slots and add, for now a 4tb drive. It would not be directly connected to any other PC, only by it's IP address on the LAN. My question is, a) can the Mini be configured to act as a TimeMachine device appearing on the LAN and b) can it use the 4tb disk on USB to be the target disk for TimeMachine backups from my iMac and Laptop.